# Hyperthreading - realy X2 cores?

Tags: hyperthreading

According to Intel (If I'm not wrong) the Hyper threading (HT) can:
- up the performances up to 30%.
- HT can make better use the CPU when there is one task which use the ALU unit and the other doing I/O (for example: one task use zip alg and the other task use to write data into the disk) - in that can the HT can be used.

So, If I have one core with HT, and I'm using 2 Simultaneously tasks which runs 2 zip algorithms, the HT will not be efficient here , because one task will be wait for other task to finish the work one the ALU unit ? (and in this case I need 2 cores, instead of one core with HT).

Did I understand what Intel means with HT ? Is it right ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didn't understand it right. When they talk about I/O, they mean writing to memory and reading from memory, not file I/O. When that zip algorithm reads the next input byte from RAM, that's I/O. And when it writes a decoded byte to RAM, that's I/O.

A hyperthreaded CPU has usually *one* unit reading instructions from memory, *two* units decoding and dispatching instructions, *two* sets of architected registers (that's the processor registers that your program sees), *one* set of rename registers, *one* set of schedulers, and *one* set of ALUs, where a non-hyperthreaded core would have one of each, and two non-hyperthreaded cores would have two of each.

Comment: ok, so when running (for example) 2 tasks and each task run a zip alg, the performance of 2 cores (without HT) vs one core with HT will be the same ?

Comment: No. Two cores have _every_ part of the processor duplicated. A single core with hyperthreading has only _some_ parts duplicated. For example, the ALUs are not duplicated.

Comment: from wiki:
"Intel claims up to a 30% performance improvement compared with an otherwise identical, non-simultaneous multithreading "